# mounted shares are not writable

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, permissions, network-shares, fstab

I have several shares that are on my windows 7 system.  The system I am accessing them from is an kubuntu 9.10 running gnome.

These are the lines I have in my /etc/fstab file

```
//192.168.1.136/Netstor /mnt/Netstor cifs username=Topsy,password=null,fmask=777,dmask=777 0 0
//192.168.1.136/htdocs /mnt/Htdocs cifs username=Topsy,password=null,fmask=777,dmask=777 0 0
//192.168.1.136/Downloads /mnt/Downloads cifs username=Topsy,password=null,fmask=777,dmask=777 0 0
```

I cannot create/change/delete anything in these mounted shares even though I have set the permissions to make them writable.  How do I resolve this?

Comment: is your user's password actually "null" or are you trying to send the empty string ("")?

Comment: no, I just removed the actual pw.  it is not null.

Comment: What happens if you add `,noperm` to the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a helpful post on the ubuntu forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1169149

With Vista/7 specific info.

This one: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=288534

Shows you how to correctly configure ubuntu, with I think a correction to your masks: 0777 instead of 777.

Comment: Adding 0777 instead of 777 did nothing.  I will follow the guide in your link and report back with results.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `rw` to the mount options. Also make sure you've supplied the correct permissions from the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how that would look?

Also the permissions are correct on the windows machine, I am able to do everything I need on the same machine when I boot into windows 7 instead (I dual boot), so that is not the issue.

Comment: `//192.168.1.136/Downloads /mnt/Downloads cifs username=Topsy,password=null,fmask=777,dmask=777,rw 0 0`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still cannot write/change/delete anything on those shares.